# "java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect" on KeyStore load

Tags: java, openssl, keystore

I've generated a pfx file following the nexts steps:

```
openssl pkcs8 –in CSD01.key –inform DER –out CSD01.pem

openssl x509 –in CSD01.cer –inform DER –out CSD01cer.pem

openssl pkcs12 –export –inkey CSD01.pem –in CSD01cer.pem –out CSD01.pfx
```

Now, I'm trying to read this CSD01.pfx file with this Java code:

```
public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(File file)
        throws KeyStoreException,
        IOException,
        CertificateException,
        NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        UnrecoverableKeyException {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(file), pwdPFX);
    String alias = ks.aliases().nextElement();

    return (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pwdPFX);
}
```

where pwdPFX is:

```
final static char[] pwdPFX = "12345678a".toCharArray();
```

but the line ks.load throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2079)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at Main.getCertificate(Main.java:105)
    at Main.main(Main.java:51)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    ... 4 more
```

I'm sure that the password is correct, because i tried with "openssl pkcs12 -in CSD01.pfx -noout" and works fine.

If I open the PFX file winth openssl info I get:

```
MAC: sha256, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 32, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: CA D8 B0 AA 79 40 AE C6 65 D9 DB 97 55 B9 95 B8 63 14 09 C4
subject=CN = BERENICE XIMO QUEZADA, name = BERENICE XIMO QUEZADA, O = BERENICE XIMO QUEZADA, C = MX, emailAddress = pruebas@pruebas.gob.mx, x500UniqueIdentifier = XIQB891116QE4, serialNumber = XIQB891116MGRMZR05
issuer=CN = AC UAT, O = SERVICIO DE ADMINISTRACION TRIBUTARIA, OU = SAT-IES Authority, emailAddress = oscar.martinez@sat.gob.mx, street = 3ra cerrada de cadiz, postalCode = 06370, C = MX, ST = CIUDAD DE MEXICO, L = COYOACAN, x500UniqueIdentifier = 2.5.4.45, unstructuredName = responsable: ACDMA-SAT
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 2048, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: CA D8 B0 AA 79 40 AE C6 65 D9 DB 97 55 B9 95 B8 63 14 09 C4
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is correct, and should work with the correct password Can you create a file with a test key (that you don't need to keep secure) that has the problem and let us look at it? (Don't directly post binary on Stack; either encode in base64 or hex -- openssl commandline can do base64 -- or use something like pastebin.) Also specify version and package of Java, in case it is due to a bug there.

Comment: Thanks for answers, not sure if I´ve done what you tell me, I´ve updated my question with the output of openssl pkcs12 -in example. Pfx -info. This certificate and all keys are for test purpose, so I don´t care about sharing it

Comment: No; the problem (which I can't reproduce) is occurring in the Java decryption, so I wanted the/an encrypted (PKCS12, binary) file to try to debug that decryption. `openssl pkcs12 -info` just confirms that openssl _can_ decrypt which you already told us -- although it shows you are apparently using 3.0, which _could_ be relevant although at this point I don't think so.

Comment: So, I'm using OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.1 14 Dec 2021) and jdk is in corretto-1.8.0.312

Comment: Okay, it does appear to be a bug. On my system I normally use Oracle Java which works in 8u301 up (below that had a different problem that didn't parse PKCS12 with PBES2 at all) but adoptium 8u322-b06 fails and on EC2 both openjdk and corretto (from extras) fail. It looks like the same as https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8278989 .

Comment: after changing  to the oracle jdk 8u311, the problem is solved, thanks @dave_thompson_085

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @dave_thompson_085 mentioned, the problem is due to the version of jdk. The solution would be to use jdk 8u311 from oracle instead of corretto