# Java Camel SSL Verification - keystore password was incorrect

Tags: java, https, apache-camel, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to send a request to this endpoint and get the response as string.keystore password is "password". But it says wrong.I need to clarify this & need any chnage in the code to work.

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
import org.apache.camel.support.jsse.KeyManagersParameters;
import org.apache.camel.support.jsse.KeyStoreParameters;
import org.apache.camel.support.jsse.SSLContextParameters;
import org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class CamelRestHttpsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        String PASSWORD ="password";

        KeyStoreParameters keyStoreParameters = new KeyStoreParameters();
        keyStoreParameters.setType("PKCS12");
        keyStoreParameters.setResource("ssl_key.p12");// Replace with your keystore path
        keyStoreParameters.setPassword(Arrays.toString(PASSWORD.toCharArray())); // Replace with your keystore password

        KeyManagersParameters keyManagersParameters = new KeyManagersParameters();
        keyManagersParameters.setKeyStore(keyStoreParameters);

        SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters = new SSLContextParameters();
        sslContextParameters.setKeyManagers(keyManagersParameters);

        JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = context.getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
        jettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(sslContextParameters);
        jettyComponent.setSslKeyPassword(Arrays.toString(PASSWORD.toCharArray()));
        jettyComponent.setSslPassword(Arrays.toString(PASSWORD.toCharArray()));
        jettyComponent.setKeystore("ssl_key.p12");

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                restConfiguration()
                        .component("jetty")
                        .scheme("https")
                        .host("127.0.0.1")
                        .port(8443)
                        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
                        .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
                        .contextPath("/api")
                        .endpointProperty("sslKeystore", "ssl_key.p12")
                        .endpointProperty("sslPassword", Arrays.toString(PASSWORD.toCharArray()))
                        .endpointProperty("sslKeyPassword", Arrays.toString(PASSWORD.toCharArray()));

                rest("/hello")
                        .get()
                        .route()
                        .transform().constant("Hello from Camel over HTTPS!")
                        .endRest();
            }
        });

        context.start();
        System.out.println("Camel context started. Access the service at: https://localhost:8443/api/hello");

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                context.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Error Msg :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.createConnector(JettyHttpComponent.java:613)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.getSslSocketConnector(JettyHttpComponent.java:593)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.getConnector(JettyHttpComponent.java:569)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.connect(JettyHttpComponent.java:326)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpCommonEndpoint.connect(HttpCommonEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpConsumer.doStart(HttpConsumer.java:58)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpConsumer.doStart(JettyHttpConsumer.java:31)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.startService(AbstractCamelContext.java:3464)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:401)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartRouteConsumers(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:319)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:213)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3167)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:2847)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2798)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2494)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:245)
    at org.example.CamelRestHttpsExample.main(CamelRestHttpsExample.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
    at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2159)
    at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:221)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1473)
    at org.apache.camel.support.jsse.KeyStoreParameters.createKeyStore(KeyStoreParameters.java:166)
    at org.apache.camel.support.jsse.KeyManagersParameters.createKeyManagers(KeyManagersParameters.java:102)
    at org.apache.camel.support.jsse.SSLContextParameters.createSSLContext(SSLContextParameters.java:262)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.createSslContextFactory(JettyHttpComponent.java:653)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jetty.JettyHttpComponent.createConnector(JettyHttpComponent.java:611)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
    ... 28 more
```

Process finished with exit code 1.

Comment: You might want to see what `Arrays.toString(PASSWORD.toCharArray())` returns. I doubt your keystore password is `['p', 'a', 's', 's', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd']`.

Comment: checkout this.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220426/java-io-ioexception-keystore-password-was-incorrect-on-keystore-load) Also double check your password

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the call `Arrays.toString(PASSWORD.toCharArray()))` which you expect to return the password as String - but it is not designed to do so:

Take the example:

```
char[] someCharArray = "password".toCharArray();
String s = Arrays.toString(someCharArray) // returns "[p, a, s, s, w, o, r, d]"
```

What you really want to do is

```
char[] someCharArray = "password".toCharArray();
String s = new String(someCharArray); // returns "password"
```